# Angular 2 is not running using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I have created one application with angular cli. While running the application with ng serve, I got below error -

[image]

Does anyone knows, how to resolve this error?

Comment: The error is there in the error stack ,please change the angular version in the package.json file or you do a npm update . The error states the version of CLI is not compatible with your angular version

Comment: I tried, but still the error is coming

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy and paste into a code block instead.

Answer (score 0):

mentioned itself.

try
npm install @angular/core@latest

Answer (score 0):

Like Parth Ghiya pointed out, the error message tells you to run the `npm install @angular/core@latest` command to update your Angular Code module to a version compatible with the Angular CLI.

If this does not solve the issue, try to remove the @angular/core line in your package.json file and running the `npm install @angular/core@latest --save` to save a reference the latest version in your package.json file.